# Karma/Jasmine Tests Broken after Updating Angular from 10.1 to 11.0/12.0

Tags: angular

Went from 10.1 -> 12.0, but the same problem exists when going from 10.1 -> 11.0

`ng test` compiles and opens web browser, but tests are unable to run.  Every test fails with the following error: `Error: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing`.

I've found in several other sources that `zone.js/dist/zone-testing` needs to be the first import within `test.ts` file.  As part of the upgrade, the import statement was changed to `import 'zone.js/testing';`.  I've tried every combination of the two, and none of them gets these tests working.

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "smart-price-v2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildDeploy": "ng build --prod --configuration production --verbose=true",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:headless": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --codeCoverage=true --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "~12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~12.0.3",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.14.2",
    "angular-google-charts": "^2.2.0",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-feature-toggle": "^10.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

*karma.conf.js*

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/SmartPriceV2'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: './junit/SmartPriceV2'
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true, // false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

*angular.json*

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "SmartPriceV2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/SmartPrice",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/akamai"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.deploy.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SmartPriceV2:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "SmartPriceV2:build:production"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "SmartPriceV2:build:test"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SmartPriceV2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "SmartPriceV2:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "SmartPriceV2:serve:production"
            },
            "test": {
              "devServerTarget": "SmartPriceV2:serve:test"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "SmartPriceV2",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "422ba9c2-8e7b-4eb7-8c0f-5e588d5241bd"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Try generating a brand new `Angular 12.0.3` project and run the unit tests. If that works, then most likely there is a configuration issue.

Go to the `package.json` of your project and compare critical packages to unit testing to the newly generated one (look for `karma`, `karma-jasmine`, `jasmine`) and ensure they match. Once they do match, delete package-lock.json and run a fresh npm install.

Finally, compare `test.ts` between the two projects. Hopefully, that resolves.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ali.  I created a new project and ran tests without issue.  I cross referenced  package.json files, and got it down to only patch versions that differ.  Also made sure test.js and polyfill.ts matched between the two.  After all that, I am still getting the error.

Comment: I went to the trouble of making versions match down to the patch and it made no difference.  I've also edited my original posting to include the main configuration files, and also mention that this issue occurs for me in both Angular 11.0 and 12.0.  As soon as I downgrade to 10.1, it works again.

Comment: That is very strange. Try comparing the angular.json files with the new project and your own project, especially the testing configuration.

Comment: I am really at a loss here.  I've copied both karma.conf.js and angular.json from the working project to mine, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I finally found the issue in tsconfig.  I will post my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the issue was caused by my tsconfig settings.  Not sure if I missed documentation somewhere, but I had to change the module setting to `es2020` and the target setting to `es2017`.

Thanks to [AliF50](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7365461/alif50) for suggesting to use a new project to compare configurations.  After about 8 hours of comparing and testing, I found the answer.